# Footer not showing in website depending on which item is loaded

Tags: html, website-design, tags, footer

I designed a website which is having an issue, but I checked the html tagging very well and cannot fix it.

If you go to this item: http://www.tahara.es/store/headbands/11/Ivory-Turquoise-headband
You will see the FOOTER display normally.

However if you go to this other item: http://www.tahara.es/store/headscarves/15/Grey-and-ivory-with-stoned-flower-Headscarf

The footer does not show.

Any clue of what I am missing or adding? The footer DIV is like this: `<div id="footer">`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **programming** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Programming questions may be asked at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. 


Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page missing the footer isn't finished generating. If you look at the HTML source code, you'll notice that it stops outputting any HTML after your right-hand side bar. Most likely there's a fatal error in your PHP code (or whatever language it's using) that's forcing the script to stop processing at that point.